# Unable to create a constant value of type (type) Only primitive types when i try to filter by concatened strings

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to filter users by their full name with linq to sql:

```
string agentName = "Jhone Doe TheFirst";


db.User.Where(a => agentName == (a.Person.Name+ ' ' + 
                                 a.Person.FirstName + ' ' + 
                                 a.Person.LastName).ToString() 
                    && !a.Deleted)
```

But when I execute this comand, an execption is thrown:

> Unable to create a constant value of type (type) Only primitive types
>   ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported.

It's not posible to concat the strings?

How can I filter the users by the person full name?

Its linq to sql, so I can't create a method that returns the full name of the person and do a `Person.GetFullName()`

Comment: it's a string i pass as a parameter, edited

Comment: Have you tried using `" "` instead of `' '`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i must admit that i'm not that familiar with Linq-To-Sql, so this is just a guess. Maybe one of these columns is nullable and the concatenation also yields `NULL`, then you can avoid this by using the  null-coalescing operator:

```
db.User.Where(a => (agentName == (a.Person.Name      ?? "") + " " 
                              +  (a.Person.FirstName ?? "") + " " 
                              +  (a.Person.LastName  ?? ""))  && !a.Deleted)
```

Note that i've also replaced `' '` with `" "`.

Comment: Already +1-ed but would just point out that `string.Join` would be even tidier

Comment: @Sayse: _"LINQ to SQL does not support the following String methods: ..... String.Format, String.Join "_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672(v=vs.110).aspx